# Apple security fob

Tags: bluetooth, nfc

I work with a software development team inside local government. Our team have developed an app for Apple IPhone 6 SE with Cordova that requires carers to "check-in" to client visits. Clients typically are vulnerable people, like the aged and severely disabled.

We would like the check-in to be possible only when the carer is at a client's home. We absolutely need to ensure this, to prevent potential fraud.

One idea that has been touted is a fob kept in the client's home alongside their care docs. The fob will contain a code identifying the client. Only when the fob is plugged into the IPhone will the app allow checkin.

Would any of you know if such a device exists? Or a similar type of solution?

IBeacons have been mentioned but are too expensive per unit.

Comment: What is an acceptable price? What volume is required. You can but basic bluetooth beacons from Chinese suppliers in small volume for under $US5 each. These use standard ICs. Most "beacons" are vastly overpriced compared to the cost of their components.  | | A FOB does not need to be "attache" to the phone - It can simply need to be in the immediate vicinity and could eg be securely enclosed in a wall ect mounted box etc.

Comment: Maybe NFC tags? I don't know if this would work with your setup, but its an idea!

Comment: iBeacons also aren't what you want anyways; they're designed to have a static transmitter SCREAMING that it's around, while devices can just sort of listen in.

Comment: Is hardware authentication required, or would a software solution and a general purpose transmitter be fine?

Comment: Even now, beacons are probably the best solution, or use geo location on the mobile.